# How to iterate a List of HashMap in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a requirement where in I receive a List of HashMap from a database query and I've to display that on the JSP.

The JSON object looks like below:

```
[
    {"UNIT_NM":"ATLANTA",    "UNIT_CD":"A00"},
    {"UNIT_NM":"ATLANTA CKO","UNIT_CD":"A00"},
    {"UNIT_NM":"DALLAS",     "UNIT_CD":"D00"},
    {"UNIT_NM":"DALLAS CKO", "UNIT_CD":"D00"}
]
```

I've to display it in dropdown like:

```
"<option value='A00'> A00  ATLANTA</option>";
"<option value='A00'> A00 ATLANTA CKO</option>";
"<option value='D00'> D00 DALLAS</option>";
"<option value='D00'> D00 DALLAS CKO</option>";
```

The JS code is:

```
$.ajax({
         url:indexContextRoot+"populateManualCsoCodes",
         type:"post",
         async:true,
         success: function(data){
         var listItems= "<option value=''>Please Select</option>";
         $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                  listItems+= "<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>";
         });
             $("#manualCsoCodes").html(listItems);
        }
    });
```

I'm getting the dropdown as:

```
[object][Object]
[object][Object]
[object][Object]
[object][Object]
```

Any suggestions please!

Comment: @jarrod Why a downvote?!? I've clearly mentioned in my question, what was required, what code I wrote and what was the output.

Comment: Who said I down voted this?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Sorry..I thought you down voted too! Dunno why I got 2 down votes for this question. Whats wrong in it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this a bit more modular and involve lesser HTML, here's my take on this :

```
var data = [
  {
    "UNIT_NM": "ATLANTA",
    "UNIT_CD": "A00"
  }, 
  {
    "UNIT_NM": "ATLANTA CKO",
    "UNIT_CD": "A00"
  }, 
  {
    "UNIT_NM": "DALLAS",
    "UNIT_CD": "D00"
  }, 
  {
    "UNIT_NM": "DALLAS CKO",
    "UNIT_CD": "D00"
  }
];


//init first option
var $option = $("<option/>", {
    "value": '',
    "html": "Please Select"
});

//add that to an array
var options = [$option];

//iterate over data
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    // value now contains a row eg., when key = 0, value =  { "UNIT_NM": "ATLANTA", "UNIT_CD": "A00" }

    //clone the default option, change the value and the HTML, then push into options array
    options.push($option.clone().val(value.UNIT_CD).html(value.UNIT_CD + " " + value.UNIT_NM));
});

//add that array into select
$("#manualCsoCodes").html(options);
```

The idea is to create an `options` array, which fills up with jQuery objects with tag name `option` and then place that in the `select` tag. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/cHqsJ/2/)

Oh, before i forget, `each` iterates row-wise. So, in any iteration of `each`, you'll get a row of data. For example,

> if `key === 2`, then `value === {
>       "UNIT_NM": "DALLAS",
>       "UNIT_CD": "D00"
>     }`

So, to access `UNIT_NM` & `UNIT_CD`, you'll have to use `value.UNIT_NM` & `value.UNIT_CD` respectively. For more info on `each`, see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! "zerkms" replied before you, but still I accept your answer for a nice description.

Answer (score 3):

The each() callback function has two parameters: 1) The index of the array element, and 2) The array element.  So `key` is going to be 0, 1, 2, etc. and `value` is going to be the js object at that index position.  So you need to do:

```
$.each(data, function(key, obj) {
      var str = obj["UNIT_CD"];
      listItems+= "<option value='" + str + "'>" + str + " " + obj["UNIT_NM"] + "</option>";
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listItems+= "<option value='" + value.UNIT_CD + "'>" + value.UNIT_CD + " " + value.UNIT_NM + "</option>";
```

PS: you could do that yourself if you used `console.log(value);`

Comment: @tarares: you could at least upvote it then :-)